# Windows 8 System-Wide Program Installation Problems

Tags: windows-8, freeze, uninstall

**TL;DR:** My computer isn't installing or uninstalling programs. It freezes at some point in the process.

I've been having lots of issues installing and uninstalling all kinds of software in Windows 8. I've had this specific image for about 2 years and I was installing *LogMeIn Hamachi* when this issue first occurred. The network adapter could not be enabled and the application as a whole was causing a lot of trouble, so I uninstalled it. For three hours it was stuck at the last part of installation. I'm not sure what the issue was but I decided to kill the task. I restarted my computer and it was working fine until I tried to open Steam. I checked their debug.log file and this was spit out:

> Error fetching PAC URL from DHCP: 2 [0102/194148:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(405)] pipe error: 232

To me, it seems like an adapter issue. But, the problem doesn't stop there. I've fixed the Steam error by disabling the Hamachi TAP service in my service settings, but now I've tried installing (and uninstalling) programs from my operating system. Every single time it just pauses at some point and never recovers. I try to cancel it and it never closes and requires me to kill the task. This just happened when trying to install Visual Studio. I had it on for a good 12 hours and it still did not complete.

I also recently installed oculus rift drivers for updating my new dev kit and had issues with that until I uninstalled it.

I would rather not reinstall Windows as it is a tedious process and I like my system the way it is. I did a [Malwarebytes](http://malwarebytes.org/) scan and nothing of importance was in log. It seems like a registry issue to me but I have no idea how to fix it and hopefully someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening command prompt in administrator mode and running "sfc /scannow" then run a chkdsk.
Here's a guide for chkdsk http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/433-disk-check.html